# How to animate a complex function with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, complex-numbers

I want to make an animation with the function `((phi^n)-((-1/phi)^n))/(5^0.5)` (Binet's formula) as n ∈ ℝ,
so that the graph starts as a straight line on the real axes then shifts into the actual graph.
I have tried to add

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
.
.
.
    def g(val):
        main_graph.set_ydata(imag(f(x))*val)
        return main_graph,
    animation = FuncAnimation(main_graph, func=g, frames=arange(0, 10, 0.1), interval=10)
plt.show
```

However, it did not work and I have no clue why I followed various tutorials and all of them had the same result (An error)
I also tried

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
.
.
.
def init():
    main_graph.set_ydata([np.nan] * len(real(f(x))))
    return main_graph,
def g(val):
    main_graph.set_ydata(imag(f(x))*val)
    return main_graph,
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(main_graph, g, init_func=init, interval=2, blit=True, save_count=50)
```

The error, in both cases, is `AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute 'canvas'`.
 Here is the full code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from numpy import arange, real, imag
phi = (1+(5**0.5))/2
x = arange(0,5,0.01)
def f(x):
    return ((phi**(x+0j))-((-1/phi)**(x+0j)))/(5**0.5)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0.0))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
#labels for x and y axes
plt.xlabel('real')
plt.ylabel('imag')
plt.grid(alpha=.4,linestyle=':')
main_graph, = plt.plot(real(f(x)),imag(f(x)), label='((phi**(x+0j))-((-1/phi)**(x+0j)))/(5**0.5)')
plt.legend()
    def g(val):
        main_graph.set_ydata(imag(f(x))*val)
        return main_graph,
    animation = FuncAnimation(main_graph, func=g, frames=arange(0, 10, 0.1), interval=10)
plt.show()
```

To see the final graph use this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange, real, imag
phi = (1+(5**0.5))/2
x = arange(0,5,0.01)
def f(x):
    return ((phi**(x+0j))-((-1/phi)**(x+0j)))/(5**0.5)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0.0))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
#labels for x and y axes
plt.xlabel('real')
plt.ylabel('imag')
plt.grid(alpha=.4,linestyle=':')
main_graph, = plt.plot(real(f(x)),imag(f(x)), label='((phi**(x+0j))-((-1/phi)**(x+0j)))/(5**0.5)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are trying to animate a plot ("main_graph"), instead of animating the Figure. In the FuncAnimation, you need to change "main_graph" to "fig".

Comment: @fdireito , unfortunately, this is not the case, although thanks anyway, there is already someone who answered my question perfectly.

Comment: Good that you had your problem solved. But my comment still stands. Compare the first argument of your FuncAnimation() implementation with the one in the answer you've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adapted the example from matplotlib's animation [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/animation_api.html). Here's how the code has been modified to allow for the modification of axis elements (in this case, the legend) by setting `blit=False`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from numpy import arange, real, imag
phi = (1+(5**0.5))/2
x = arange(0,5,0.01)
def f(x):
    return ((phi**(x+0j))-((-1/phi)**(x+0j)))/(5**0.5)
fig = plt.figure()
main_graph, = plt.plot(real(f(x)),imag(f(x)), label='((phi**(x+0j))-((-1/phi)**(x+0j)))/(5**0.5)')
#labels for x and y axes
plt.xlabel('real')
plt.ylabel('imag')
plt.grid(alpha=.4,linestyle=':')
#plt.legend(loc=4)

def init():
    global legs
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0.0))
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.set_ylim(-4,4)
    legs=ax.legend(loc=4, prop={'size': 12})
    return main_graph, 
    
def g(val):
    main_graph.set_ydata(imag(f(x))*val)
    label = '((phi**(x+0j))-((-1/phi)**(x+0j)))/(5**0.5)x{}'.format(val)
    legs.texts[0].set_text(label)
    return main_graph, 
#Note that blit has been set to False, because axes elements are being modified
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=g,frames=arange(0, 10, 0.1), init_func=init,interval=10,blit=False)
animation.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=30)
plt.show()
```

Here's how the animation is:
[image: animation]